# Retrieve array from MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, casting

I try to read out all fields of an array of a document in MongoDB.
I tried to adapt a posted solution from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957900/reading-an-array-in-mongodb) to my use case, but I get the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList
    at Connector.getTopics(Connector.java:249)
```

Basically I want to read out the array in "Topics" of the first document in the collection "Topics" and save the values to an arrayList and return it.

```
public ArrayList<String> getTopics() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("JMS");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Topics"); 

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Document document = collection.find(eq("_id", 1.0)).first();

                ListIterator<Object> topics = ((BasicDBList) document.get("Topics")).listIterator();


                while(trustedList.hasNext()){

                    Object nextItem = topics.next();



                    list.add((String) nextItem);


                }


        return list;

}
```

I do not completely understand the posted solution to get all values of the array, so I am a bid confused how to correct the cast error.

Comment: I'm not sure about MongoDB, but if the method `document.get("Topics")).listIterator()` returns an `ArrayList` why don't you just use it as such, instead of casting it to `BasicDBList` (which might be deprecated API, just a guess)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to store topics in a BasicDBList object:

```
 BasicDBList topics = (BasicDBList) document.get("Topics");
```

Then you can iterate it and store into your array:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Object element: topics) {
     result.add((String) element);
}
```

Comment: Im a bid confused, where is topicsMongo actually used?

Comment: I mean that BasicDBList is like a Java List so you don't need get the iterator, you can iterate on it in a "foreach", like an Array: I wrote 'list' when I should wrote 'topicsMongo'. Now the answer is edited, thanks to @the4kman

Comment: mhh it says: "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList"